# Pipe clamps - availability of 1" black pipe

Tags: clamps

I wanted to buy two more sets of black pipe clamps for 1" pipe, don't see them available now! Has 3/4" black pipe replaced the older 1" ??

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. I'm sure this is going to come down to a local supply issue (possibly related to Covid, as many shortages are currently) rather than 1" being replaced across the board. How many potential vendors do you have within driving distance, and have you tried them all?

Comment: I can locate 1" black pipe, can not locate clamps for this size pipe...

Comment: I just found [these on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Heavy-Clamp-Fixture-Woodworking-Water/dp/B07R647F8K) (in the US) by searching for `1" pipe clamp`. There do seem to be a lot more options for 3/4", though.

Comment: *"I can locate 1" black pipe, can not locate clamps for this size pipe..."* That isn't at all clear from the wording of the Question. I was going to say please edit accordingly but can I just check are you merely asking for a yes/no? We can't actually provide potential or alternate sources for you because this would make this a shopping question, which were ruled off topic early on.

Answer (score 4):

> Has 3/4" black pipe replaced the older 1" ?

Remember that the size of pipe (in the US, at least) is determined by it's *inside diameter*. Nominal 3/4" black iron pipe has an outside diameter of about 1", and will fit in clamp heads meant for 3/4" pipe.

I don't think I've ever seen clamp heads for nominal 1" pipe. That's not to say that they don't exist, but 3/4" and 1/2" have been the two sizes commonly used for pipe clamps in the US for at least 25 years and probably longer.

Comment: This may be useful: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/170815/25178